# Reducing sign interspace in slightly too wide equations

Tags: spacing, equations

Some equations are sometimes slightly too wide. One way is to manually add `\!` commands wherever it seems relevant in the equation. Is there an automatic alternative to:

```
x\!=\!y\!+\!z
```

Comment: Why should you want this? Just to break uniformity in your document?

Comment: I have a few equations that are a bit too wide. I want to locally slightly reduce inter-space to avoid margin non-alignment.

Comment: This is surely the last remedy to try.

Comment: breaking the equations onto two lines does not seem recommended in the current configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only do this as a last resort....

[image]

```
$x=y+z$

\advance\thickmuskip -2mu 
\advance\medmuskip -1mu minus -1mu

$x=y+z$
```